# Is there a definitive location for Tor Project releases?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, development

Is there a definitive location for various Tor Project latest releases? Some Linux repos as an example will have a "latest" point that redirects requests to the newest published release. I'm looking for something like https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/latest.tar.gz.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the answer is no. People talked about the idea before. You might create a ticket asking about the issue. I know orbot provides latest release download link and it's helpful.